# Java detect circular references during custom cloning

Tags: java

I am writing a custom clone method for each entity. for deep copy is there a way to detect circular references or do I have to manually figure it out and restrict cloning to be unidirectional instead of bidirectional.

For example we use hibernate an hence a User object has a reference to Address and Address has a reference to User. Trying to see if doing a deep copy of Address as well as User is possible without running into circular reference issues

Comment: To handle circular references an IdentityMap can be used. This keep track of every object it find and when you serialize or copy data you can use this to ensure you handle repeated objects correctly. e.g. you might just have the same object many times in a structure and you don't want to turn these into different objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To implement this, you need a Map of references to already cloned objects. We implemented deep clone something like this:

In our entity base class:

```
public void deepClone() {
    Map<EntityBase,EntityBase> alreadyCloned = 
        new IdentityHashMap<EntityBase,EntityBase>();
    return deepClone(this,alreadyCloned);
}

private static EntityBase deepClone(EntityBase entity, 
                                    Map<EntityBase,EntityBase> alreadyCloned) {
    EntityBase clone = alreadyCloned.get(entity);
    if( clone != null ) {
        return alreadyClonedEntity;
    }
    clone = newInstance(entity.getClass);
    alreadyCloned.put(this,clone);
    // fill clone's attributes from original entity. Call
    // deepClone(entity,alreadyCloned) 
    // recursively for each entity valued object.
    ...
}
```

Comment: HashMap is a terrible idea to use in such a case (both can be bogus and it's slow). IdentityHashMap is a lot better.

Comment: +1 Great comment. Updated my answer and fixed my own code :) But I have to admit that HashMap is not slow. IMHO it is unbelievable fast.

Comment: The difference in slowness between HashMap and IdentityHashMap depends on the .hashCode and .equals implementations of the keys. If these are bad, HashMap gets slow (and in this algorithm you may get wrong results, like merging different objects because they are equal).

Comment: @Daniel, allocation on put and tree alike structure is a high (and unnecessary) price to pay for a hash table. You can have totally lock-free (concurrent) hashmap w/o allocation on put. Btw. IdentityHashMap (on top of not using `Object.hashCode` which is a relatevely slow virtual call) uses linear-probe internal structure which beats the tree alike one of HashMap in every possible way.

Comment: Your code will not work in the following situation where an Address has a user object as well as a createby user object and modified by user object.

Comment: Is there sth. wrong, you return a variable, that is no where declared? return alreadyClonedEntity;

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel: Thank you very much for this great answer!

I just used your code and modified it a little based on my needs which makes it easier to use with subclasses. Maybe someone else is interested in that as well so here is my code for the base class:

```
/**
 * Perform a deep clone.
 * 
 * @return Deep Clone.
 * @throws CloneNotSupportedException
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public VersionedEntityImpl deepClone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Map<VersionedEntityImpl, VersionedEntityImpl> alreadyCloned = new IdentityHashMap<VersionedEntityImpl, VersionedEntityImpl>();
    return deepClone(this, alreadyCloned);
}

/**
 * Perform a deep clone.
 * 
 * @param entity
 * @param alreadyCloned
 * @return Deep Clone.
 * @throws CloneNotSupportedException
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected VersionedEntityImpl deepClone(VersionedEntityImpl entity,
        Map<VersionedEntityImpl, VersionedEntityImpl> alreadyCloned) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    if (entity != null) {
        VersionedEntityImpl clone = alreadyCloned.get(entity);
        if (clone != null) {
            return clone;
        }
        clone = entity.clone();
        alreadyCloned.put(entity, clone);
        return entity.deepCloneEntity(clone, alreadyCloned);
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Method performing a deep clone of an entity (circles are eliminated automatically). Calls
 * deepClone(entity,alreadyCloned) recursively for each entity valued object.
 *
 * @param clone
 * @param alreadyCloned
 * @return clone
 * @throws CloneNotSupportedException
 */
protected abstract VersionedEntityImpl deepCloneEntity(VersionedEntityImpl clone,
        Map<VersionedEntityImpl, VersionedEntityImpl> alreadyCloned) throws CloneNotSupportedException;
```

What to put into the subclasses:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected VersionedEntityImpl deepCloneEntity(VersionedEntityImpl clone,
        Map<VersionedEntityImpl, VersionedEntityImpl> alreadyCloned) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    // fill clone's attributes from original entity. Call
    // deepClone(entity,alreadyCloned)
    // recursively for each entity valued object.
    if (this.associatedItems != null) {
        List<SomeClass> listClone = new LinkedList<SomeClass>();
        for (SomeClass someClass: this.associatedItems) {
            listClone.add((SomeClass) super.deepClone(someClass, alreadyCloned));
        }
        ((SomeOtherClass) clone).setAssociatedItems(listClone);
    }
    ((SomeOtherClass) clone).setYetAnotherItem((YetAnotherClass) super.deepClone(this.yai, alreadyCloned));

    return clone;
}
```

It is not perfect as of yet but it gets the job done nicely for now :)