# Is there any way to find circular references?

Tags: java, gson

I have to serialize very complicated classes as JSON. The serialization fails with a stack overflow. This is a known problem - serialization fails if there are circular references. Simplest case: Object A keeps a reference to object B, while object B keeps a reference to A.

Unfortunately, objects to be serialized are too complex (more then 100 fields each), and it is almost impossible to find such dependencies by code review. Gson logs only stack overflow exception with no additional info.

Is there any way to detect cycles?

Comment: When the serialization fails, what error message are you seeing? Does the error message cue to any key lines of code? If so, this is where I'd start.

Comment: I get lot of Stack overflow exceptions with the same line number, without message.

Comment: Yes, those line numbers **are** the key. Why are you not showing the relevant code and the involved line?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation. If the circular references are due to a bug or occur only in a narrow range of cases, I would try to address the specific case.

If the situation is general in that object graphs with cycles can routinely occur and it's a matter of detecting them, it may be worth trying to implement a custom solution based on reflection (to get all fields of classes in the object graph, as well as their value), and storing the values of reference types in an [IdentityHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) to detect revisited objects.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157764/java-detect-circular-references-during-custom-cloning) for an additional discussion on the use of identity hash maps to detect circular references.

Comment: Thanks. I will think about. It looks like reflection is only solution :(

Answer (score 0):

A simple DFS algorithm would do the trick

- Create 2 hash sets: `visiting`, and `visited`.
- Recourse through the Json

  - If current node is in `visiting`

    - print "circular reference found"
  - Else If current node is in `visited`

    - print "crossover found"
  - Else

    - add current node to `visiting`
    - recourse through children nodes
    - remove current node from `visiting` and add it to `visited`

Comment: Borrowing from @Derefacto: Use `IdentityHashMap` for `visiting` and `visited`

Comment: `Collections.newSetFromMap(new IdentityHashMap<>())` will be useful for this purpose where map values do not have importance

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem in TypeScript recently and put it on a npm package to make it publicly available. There is a `hasCircularReference()` and a `isIdentical()` functions, the latter is for data comparison and has circular reference support which you have to opt-in.

Now, I don't have plans to ever write in Java, but you can check out the algorithm and maybe create a Java version. The only thing I would ask is give credit where credit us due :). It comes with extensive tests.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@enio.ai/data-ferret

Good luck with the serializer if you haven't solved it already.